# When i setCurrentItem in the ViewPager, the ViewPager load data of 5 pages,why?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

The ViewPager defaults to  one page  that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy by the method `setOffscreenPageLimit().` But when i setCurrentItem, it still load data of two front pages，this mean that it request data of 5 pages. How can i avoid this, just load data of 3 pages?

```
FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new WorksFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),ids);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItem);
```

Comment: What data are you requesting in your fragments, an external json?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `setUserVisibleHint` in your Fragment and load your data inside it.

Here is an sample that works for me.

```
public class ViewPagerFragmentSample extends ListFragment{
    ...  
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            new AsyncListViewLoader().execute(); //Replace with your method
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it just like a lazy load fragment, the eager loading is dismissed.